# Load the image even with the widget image

Tags: flutter

the error is this

Unable to get status of file `"C:\Users\gio\Desktop\flutter\TodoAppV2\assets\Magic_Menu_Image.webp": file not found.`

but i'm not able to load it. Below is my code.

main.dart:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Home'),
  ),
  drawer: Drawer(
    child: ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      children: <Widget>[
        DrawerHeader(
          child: null,//Image.asset('assets/Magic_Menu_Image.jpg'),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: Container(
            color: Colors.orange[900],
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(
                  Icons.home,
                  size: 30,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Home',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,),
                )
              ]
            )
          ),
        )
      ]
    )
  ),
);
```

}
}

and isn't in the pubspec.yaml file:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/Magic_Menu_Image.jpg
```

If someone could help with fixing this error.

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do with this code? Share some background.

Comment: Have you searched in the project for `Magic_Menu_Image.webp` to see if anyone is referencing it?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi yeah and i haven't seen anything

Comment: @Belle what i've shared is the important part the rest is the main function and the class definition

Comment: Your file extensions are different. Your code says .jpg but your error says webp. Which one is right?

Comment: @S.Ramjit the webp extension is the extension of a precedent file the right extension is jpg

Comment: Do you have that file in your project. Even if you are not using the image, the system will still look it up since you use it in the pubspec.yaml file.

Comment: @guanwenyan nope I've already deleted it

Comment: If you deleted the image, you should also delete - assets/Magic_Menu_Image.jpg

Comment: @guanwenyan but I need that image